# Images appearing distorted depsite putting them in the ldpi folder, they apper perfect in screenshots

Tags: android, image, screenshot, distortion

I have some image resources that are properly sized and put into the drawable-land-ldpi and drawable-port-ldpi. When I see how the app looks, the images appear horizontally streched in landscape and vertically stretched in portrait.

However, if I take a screenshot with DDMS, they appear perfectly sized with no distortions at all! What's happening?

It's on android 4.0.3, an actual device. With the barest simple image layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/imageb" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Emulator or device? Which device? Which android version? Layout code?

Comment: Device, it's similar to a crane ainol novo 7, android 4.0.3, and the layout code is as simple as possible. Just a
`
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/imageb" />
`

Comment: Have you tried a different image? Have you tried setting the scaleType of the ImageView?

Comment: Three different images and I can confirm that they look fine in image editors, in the screenshots, just on the device they look stretched.

I have now tried adding 
android:scaleType="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"

 to no avail.